# error in arcore configuration for use geospatial

Tags: java, configuration, geospatial, arcore

I'm trying to develop an application with the new API of google geolocalization.
i have an error with the starting configuration of ARcode to use geospatial.

This is my error:

E/native: E0000 00:00:1655297260.231423   13723 error_policy_util.cc:263]
################ ARCore Native Error ##################
BUILD_CHANGELIST:445555480
BUILD_BASELINE_CHANGELIST:441227770
################### Stack Trace Begin ################
ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/geo/geoar_module.cc:167  https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/geo/geoar_module.cc?g=0&l=167
ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/session.cc:487  https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/core/session.cc?g=0&l=487
ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/c_api/session_lite_c_api.cc:109 https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/core/c_api/session_lite_c_api.cc?g=0&l=109
################### Stack Trace End #################

```
################### Undecorated Trace Begin  #################
FAILED_PRECONDITION: 
ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/session.cc:487

ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/geo/geoar_module.cc:167
 [type.googleapis.com/util.ErrorSpacePayload='ArStatusErrorSpace::AR_ERROR_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_LIBRARY_NOT_LINKED']
=== Source Location Trace: === 
third_party/arcore/ar/geo/geoar_module.cc:167
third_party/arcore/ar/core/session.cc:487

################### Undecorated Trace End  #################
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue on Unity where I was building for Android. This is what I did to fix this issue. I hope you can take some pointers from this and apply it to your own situation. I'm not really an Android Developer so  only have very basic understanding of Gradle.

Weirdly enough in my case this issue "suddenly" started occurring after I made a small code change to a script of a functioning application.

In the Project Settings > Player > Android > Publishing Settings, select **Custom Main Gradle Template**

Open the file and ensure the following code snippets exists:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16+' // Google.XR.ARCoreExtensions.Editor.Internal.ExternalDependencyResolverHelper.RegisterAndroidDependencies
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
**DEPS**}
```

This snippet was there by default in my case, but should ensure the play services package for location tracking is linked properly.

You can validate it's there by analyzing the apk package after building in Android Studio (Build > Analyze Package). The package will include play services property files and also one of the classes*.dex files will reference com.goog.android.gms.

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you give more details on how to ensure the services package is linked properly?